# Not able to create a link in a Jira description when creating the issue from a zap

Tags: jira, zapier

We have a Google Form where the submissions create a Google Doc. I've set up a zap in Zapier that takes some of the content of the doc and creates a new Jira issue. That all works fine. I need to add a link in the Jira issue description that links back to that Google Doc. But I can't figure out how to format that in the zap - it's just coming back as plain text. I've tried this format, but it doesn't work:
[Link Text](https://link_url)

Has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you use Jira Cloud (usually domain.atlassian.net) or Jira Server/DC (usually jira.domain.com).

**Jira Cloud syntax:**
`[Link Text](https://link_url)` (see [Atlassian documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/markdown-and-keyboard-shortcuts/))

**Jira Server/DC syntax:**
`[Link Text|https://link_url]`

Comment: Thanks - we use Jira Cloud and I've tried that syntax but it doesn't work.  I think the issue is because it's coming from a zap.

Comment: It doesn't work in Jira at all or it doesn't work from Zappier? Can you create such link in description manually by you? Explore such issue via REST API to understand how it's actually written - you might need to escape (in Zappier) some special characters, e.g. `[]()`? To se the output in REST API, simply visit `https://yourdomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/YOURISSUEKEY-1`.